# want to know the exact size of a data contend in any specified url

Tags: iphone

hi all i want to know that while specifying url in my iphone native application for downloading purpose  it works fine but if i want to know the exact size of data either in kb or in Mb coming from that url how could i do that plz guide me to do that demonstarting a sample code would be a big boost 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) can request the size of the download for the purposes of attaching a download progress indicator.